# "The database has reached its size quota"

Tags: oozie, azure-hdinsight, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a Oozie Job that used to work perfectly earlier.
But now I get this following error:

> Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The database 'v0201xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxooziemetastore' has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions. {prepstmnt 1642246000 UPDATE WF_ACTIONS SET error_code = ?, error_message = ?, external_status = ?, last_check_time = ?, pending_age = ?, status = ? WHERE id = ? [params=?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?]} [code=40544, state=S0001]
>   FailedObject: org.apache.oozie.WorkflowActionBean-0014872-140428144646972-oozie-hdp-W@RunHiveScript
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4869)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4829)
>       at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your meta-store is probably full.

You should check the SQL Azure database you're using for the metastore, and ensure it's not hitting its size cap.

If you're using 150GB of metastore space, you may have a problem since that's the current limit, but if your database is capped lower, you can just scale up the size limit.

Comment: Hive metastore is not explicitly mentioned. I used Quick Create option to create HDInsight Cluster. Is there a way to know associated metastore in this case and change its limit?

Comment: when you create the cluster, you can select external hive/oozie metstore and point to a SQL Azure instance. That's the one you're after.

Comment: My cluster is already created with Quick Create option selected. I left it default.

Comment: Ah, quick create doesn't use an external metastore, so looks like it's the one of the cluster that's full, try using custom create and setting up an external store (you'll need to create a SQL Azure database to keep it in first) then you'll have more space and metastore persistence independent of the cluster.